# Upsert into sub document in couchbase using N1QL

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have document like below in couchbase.

```
{
  "templateType": "EMAIL",
  "displayName": "Email for user",
  "structure": {
    "{twitterLink}": "http://www.twitter.com/",
    "{facebookLink}": "http://www.facebook.com",
    "{instagramLink}": "http://instagram.com",
     "{websiteLink}": "http://mavenir.com"
   },
  "backendPlaceholders": [
    "{ACTIVATION_URL}",
    "{USERNAME}"
  ]
}
```

I want to insert a new entry 'linkedIn'  inside "structure" so that my doc will look like below,

```
{
  "templateType": "EMAIL",
  "displayName": "Email for user",
  "structure": {
    "{twitterLink}": "http://www.twitter.com/",
    "{facebookLink}": "http://www.facebook.com",
    "{instagramLink}": "http://instagram.com",
    "{linkedIn}": "http://www.linkedin.com",
    "{websiteLink}": "http://mavenir.com",
    "{linkedIn}": "http://www.linkedin.com"
  },
  "backendPlaceholders": [
    "{ACTIVATION_URL}",
    "{USERNAME}"
  ]
}
```

May I know how to do it in N1QL ? The structure is not an array and it is a sub document. I am not sure how to do it in N1QL.

Comment: I know your question asks about N1QL, but if you only plan to do this to one document at a time, the subdocument API of whatever SDK you're using will likely be faster. Just a tip, you can ignore me if you want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use UPDATE statement

```
UPDATE default AS d
SET d.`structure`.`{linkedIn}` = "http://www.linkedin.com"
WHERE ....
```